# PHP: Cant extend execution time of function

Tags: php, server, execution-time

I have an app that scans 100+ domains at the same time my problem is the execution time, I cant extend more than 1.8 min, and displays 404 not found.

This is my code on testing the execution time.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
// current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

sleep(120);

// wake up !
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

?>
```

I want to run my functions until it finishes its task.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to do it on a webpage? why don't you write a cron to do this task?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, yes, I need to make a scan first to get the information I need, I have cron too, but that is for checking the info of the scanned domains.

Comment: so how long does this process take?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo the max is 1.8 min base from the error it shown.

Comment: 404 is `page not found` error, 504 is timeout error

Comment: change it in php.ini file, `max_execution_time = 10// seconds` and restart the web server

Comment: The timeout the OP is talking about may be the network timeout for the request to a domain `that scans 100+ domains` with a bad URL `404 not found`, for example. Which is totally different then the script execution time.  So there is too much unknown (how a request or the domain is checked is a mystery, etc..) to really answer.  In any case a error call to a single domain should not bring the whole process down, so you need to `try{  }catch` that or do some other form of error recovery.  404's happen for various reasons, you have to account for some loss over the network.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by changing the value for the param `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`,

Comment: Your code works for me fine. No error shows to me

Comment: @A.ANoman I tried that too but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set_time_limit()` for this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: stil the same sir, the execution time did'nt change.

Comment: try this `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe its your web server? try checking if it has a runtime limit

Answer (score 0):

You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.

If you dont have access to php.ini contact your service provider.

Other option is set bacground script or cronjob  on server which takes task from database and maintain its result and create webservice that will montior this process.